When I hit a break point, the file becomes read only
I'm using Visual Studio 2022, 64-bit Version 17.10.4 on windows 11.
When I set a break point in my C# code, the execution of the code stops at the break point, however, the file becomes read only. If I let the execution continue, the file becomes editable and I can modify code without stopping my debug session. However, I can not modify a file while I am on the break point while debugging
How do I get VS to let me edit files while in the break point?
I have Enable all 3 debug items

Enable Hot Reload
Enable hot Reload when starting without debugging
Apply Hot Reload on File Save

In response to NKR request, I have added sample code for reference.
In scenario 1,
I add a break point on the variable testV. The code execution stops on the break point, however, if one looks at the file name in the IDE, it now has a small locked icon, and 'Read Only' next to the file name in the IDE. Therefore, I am unable to adjust the variable value from 1 to the number 3 while in the debugger session.
public async Task<TelemetryTrendDataDto> TelemetryTrendData(TelemetryTrendDataInput telemetryTrendDataInput)
{
    var testV = 1; //debugger
    return = await GetCurrentUserOrganizationIds(_userOrganizationUnitManager);
}

In scenario 2,
In this scenario, I follow almost the same steps above, however, once the break point is reached, and the file becomes read-only, I 'F5', meaning I let the execution continue and by doing that, the file becomes editable.
Note: I do not stop the debugger session
However, once the execution continues 'F5', I can adjust the testV to a new value and once the break point is triggered, the variable value is adjusted.
In summary, I would like to archive scenario 2 while in the current debug/break point session.
Regarding Sir Rufo and Dou Xu-MSFT comments relative to similar posts. I have followed those steps, and posted images of my setup. However, as Dou Xu-MSFT noted, "Enable Edit and Continue" has been renamed to Hot Reload but that is checked as shown in the images.



Sharing the code snippet where the issue is occurring would help.

This question is similar to: How do I enable file editing in Visual Studio's debug mode?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

With  Hot Reload , previously called Edit and Continue,  you can make changes to your code in break or run mode while debugging. However, some types of code changes are not supported by Edit and Continue. You can check Unsupported changes to code

In response to the comments, I have added sample code for reference. and updated the question for further clarity

Hi @IvanSager, what's the type of your project ? Does the issue disappear if you create a console app for test including the code var testV = 1; //debugger? Besides, confirm again: Do you meet these Unsupported scenarios

@Dou Xu-MSF, I created a C# console App and took the same code and method and the debugging in the new sample console App worked as intended. So your idea was great, because it tells me my IDE is configured correctly.
However, my core application is a a Class Library, targeting .NET 8.0. The  scenarios that I am working on are supported, However, I do need to research what they mean by "Mixed-mode (native/managed) debugging." is unsupported. I am not sure on this so will investigate and get back

This doc Debug in mixed mode may help.

Thanks for the Mixed mode link. I'm using managed code so I am using the supported scenarios.
This has stumped me a little, so my intention is to setup a new project this weekend and migrate each domain layer over and debugger each step until I find the culprit. What a pain but I need to get this resolved.

On the basis of your migration, you can decide to cut down the code and keep the smallest part that can reproduce the problem and share them.

Thanks Dou Xu-MSFT for the thoughts. At this stage I am not sure what might be the  smallest part that can reproduce the problem but our platform is a multi layer domain project so moving this will take me a good deal of time. I will keep this post updated. Be well, Ivan

Hey Dou Xu-MSF first error appeared while debugging with a message "Changes are not allowed when unmanaged debugging is enabled". I'm going to look how to disable that in Vs2022 and will keep this post updated..

Please check if you enable  Enable native code debugging option from Project Properties->Debug->launch profiles UI
